# Performing instant super fast feedback in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a tutorial in rails that teaches on how to do super instant feed back in rails. For instance some one makes a comment on an article or someone updates their status you get it instantly without using polling. Just like when a new tweet is posted on Twitter or new status update on Facebook. I know something like an open socket but never actually tried it out. Any ideas?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

Comment: faye has an open channel. not all users should have acess to all instant feeds only user subscribed to that channel should have the feed. just like tweeter. though i do not no how to customize it to that level cos i am not so good with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter accomplishes this using ajax polling. You probably won't need to go so far as to use something like websockets.

Assuming you're using jquery, you can start by looking here: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/refresh

It's as simple as defining an action on your controller which renders *only* the content you want to keep up to date, and then triggering the refresh plugin to request that action and populate the container.

In the initial view:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#keep_me_updated').refresh('/statuses');
  });
</script>
<div id="keep_me_updated">
</div>
```

And in statuses/index:

```
<% Status.all.each do |status| %>
  <%= status.body %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I havent tried it out just yet but you answer sounds so good to be easy... thanks